# Subscribe to Firebase Join Query React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

As you can see I have 2 Main branches

**Users**

**Conversations**

Every User has many conversations in the users branch

I would like to perform a JOIN query so i only subscribe only one time by the user id

So if there is any change in any conversation of the user the callback will be called

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since firebase db is a NOSQL database, you can't use a join query.

What you can do in your case, is get the conversationId for a user, set it to a variable, and use that variable to make a listener to listen for changes in the conversation.

For example, you can do something like this:

```
getConversationId(userId, memberId){

  let conversationRef = firebaseDB.ref(`/users/${userId}/conversations/${memberId}`);

  conversationRef.once("value").then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.val()){
      let id = snapshot.val()
      let { conversationId } = id;
      this.listenConversation(conversationId);
    }
  })
}

listenConversation(conversationId){

  let conversationsRef = firebaseDB.ref(`/conversations/${conversationId}`);

  conversationsRef.on("value", snapshot => {
    // here is your data
  })
}
```